# No preview for view class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm pretty new to android but watched a tutorial and I'm trying to create a view with canvas/paint. The preview does not show in either the java class design view, inserting it into the xml, or when I run it. I was getting null pointer errors but got rid of all of those and now there are no errors that I can find. [image: blank preview]

```
    public class SudokuBoard extends View {
    private Paint stroke;
    private Paint fill;
    private Paint shadowPaint;
    private final int textSize = 10;
    private int cellSize;
    private int[][] board;

    private final int boardColor;

    public SudokuBoard(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context);
        board = new int[9][9];

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SudokuBoard, 0, 0);

        try {
            boardColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.SudokuBoard_squareBG, 0);
        }
        finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
                board[i][j] = i;
            }
        }

        stroke = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        stroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        stroke.setTextSize(textSize);
        stroke.setColor(0x333333);

        fill = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        fill.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        fill.setTextSize(textSize);
        fill.setColor(0x333333);

        shadowPaint = new Paint(0);
        shadowPaint.setColor(0xff101010);
        shadowPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
        super.onMeasure(width, height);

        int dimension = Math.min(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        cellSize = dimension / 9;

        setMeasuredDimension(dimension, dimension);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(), stroke);
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            if(i%3 == 0){
                stroke.setStrokeWidth(16);
                canvas.drawLine(cellSize*i, 0, cellSize*i, getWidth(), stroke);
                canvas.drawLine(0, cellSize*i, getWidth(), cellSize*i, stroke);
            }
            else {
                stroke.setStrokeWidth(10);
                canvas.drawLine(cellSize*i, 0, cellSize*i, getWidth(), stroke);
                canvas.drawLine(0, 0, cellSize*i, getWidth(), stroke);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
                if(i%3 == 0) { }
                //canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(board[i][j]), 5,5, brush );
                    int value = board[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, so there are no errors. what is your question, then?

Comment: How are you using this custom View in your MainActiviy.java or activity_main.xml?

Comment: My question is why can't I see the preview? I'm using it in my activity llike this. But in all the tutorials I've seen I should be seeing something in my screenshot where it just says "Sudoku Board" with a wrench
`  <com.example.sudoku2021java.models.SudokuBoard ..... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started a new class from scratch until I figured out the problem.

The issue was with onMeasure, getWidth and getHeight do not have values until time of rendering. Therefore calling setMeasuredDimension(dimension, dimension); was setting it to 0, 0

Instead, use int height = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels; (If someone has a better way of doing this feel free to edit)